# How to Parse JSON Data like array-->Object-->Object with value

Tags: java, android, json

I'm New to android development. I just know very little about JSON. I used Json simple format.

```
{

"worldpopulation": 
[
     {
         "rank":1,"country":"China",
         "population":"1,354,040,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
     }, 

     {
         "rank":2,"country":"India",
         "population":"1,210,193,422",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
     }
  ]
}
```

In above JSON data we can simply call rank, country after getting JSOn array worldpopulation.

Now I have JSON data showed below, here JSON array is same I think since item is present I don't know. Then it has objects as numbers under that it has country.

```
{  
"Items":"0 to 2",
"worldpopulation":[  
  {  
     "0":{  
        "country":"China",
            "population":"1,354,040,000",
            "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
     }
  },
  {  
     "1":{  
        "country":"India",
            "population":"1,210,193,422",
             "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

Now I don't know how to call country, population and flag.

Is it same method as. Jsonobject.getstring("rank"); after jsonarray("worldpopulation");

Or different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as following

```
try {
    JSONObject reader = new JSONObject("your json str");

    JSONArray items = reader.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject jsonProgram = items.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject yourObject = null;
        if (i == 0) {
            yourObject = jsonProgram.getJSONObject("0");
        } else {
            yourObject = jsonProgram.getJSONObject("1");
        }

        //Do here what did before with yourObject

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.i("Test", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but you might want to use `optJSONArray()` and `optJSONObject()` instead of wrapping it all in a try/catch block. Both return null if the item you are trying to get was not a JSONArray or JSONObject respectively.

Comment: I agree with optFunction analogues,  they are returns null if not found but new JSONObject() still throws exeption